# How to iterate through an array of custom objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

How do i iterate the array allInfo for the teamFullNames property?

```
NSMutableArray *allInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

        ExtraTeamInfoObject *temp = [[ExtraTeamInfoObject alloc] init];

        temp.teamFullNames = _teamFullNames[i];
        temp.teamStadiumNames = _teamStadiumNames[i];
        temp.stadiumCapacity = _stadiumCapacity[i];
        temp.clubFoundationDate = _clubFoundationDate[i];
        temp.stadiumBuiltYear = _stadiumBuiltYear[i];
        temp.teamCity = _teamCity[i];
        temp.clubPresident = _clubPresident[i];
        temp.headCoach = _headCoach[i];
        temp.championshipsWon = _championshipsWon[i];
        temp.domesticCupsWon = _domesticCupsWon[i];
        temp.domesticLeagueCupsWon = _domesticLeagueCupsWon[i];
        temp.domesticSuperCupsWon = _domesticSuperCupsWon[i];
        temp.championsleaguesWon = _championshipsWon[i];
        temp.europaleaguesWon = _europaleaguesWon[i];
        temp.europeanSuperCupsWon = _europeanSuperCupsWon[i];
        temp.worldclubchampionshipsWon = _worldclubchampionshipsWon[i];

        [allInfo addObject:temp];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Show me the goods %@", allInfo[i].teamFullNames); // its not working at all
    }


}
```

Can anyone help me iterate this array? I've tried so many combinations but no success..

Cheers.

Comment: What's the problem you're having? What does "its not working" mean, _specifically_?

Comment: what is `NSLog(@"%@", allInfo);` put console of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Key-Value Coding, using valueForKey. This will give you an array of all the names.

```
NSLog(@"Show me the goods %@", [allInfo valueForKey:@"teamFullNames"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Show me the goods"); 
for (ExtraTeamInfoObject *obj in allInfo) {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj.teamFullNames);
}
```